# configuring multiple Vhosts in AMQP in rabbitmq configuration spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

i'm implementing a project where i have to send messages across different vhosts in rabbitmq. using SimpleRoutingConnectionFactory but get java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot determine target ConnectionFactory for lookup key [null]. 
Anyone who has an idea how to implement such below is my configuration class code.

```
@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
public class RabbitMQConfiguration {

@Autowired
ConnectionProperties connect;

// client1 exchanges
@Bean
public TopicExchange client1Exchange() {
    TopicExchange ex = new TopicExchange("ex_client1");
    ex.setAdminsThatShouldDeclare(client1());
    return ex;
}

// client2 exchange
@Bean
public TopicExchange client2Exchange() {
    TopicExchange ex = new TopicExchange("ex_client2");
    ex.setAdminsThatShouldDeclare(client2Admin());
    return ex;
}

@Bean
public Queue client1Queue() {
    Queue queue = new Queue("client1_queue");
    queue.setAdminsThatShouldDeclare(client1());
    return queue;
}

@Bean
public Binding client1Binding() {
    Binding binding = BindingBuilder.bind(client1Queue())
            .to(client1Exchange())
            .with("client1_key");
    binding.setAdminsThatShouldDeclare(client1());
    return binding;
}


@Bean
public Queue client2Queue() {
    Queue queue = new Queue("client2_queue");
    queue.setAdminsThatShouldDeclare(client2());
    return queue;
}

@Bean
public Binding client2Binding() {
    Binding binding = BindingBuilder.bind(client2Queue())
            .to(client2Exchange())
            .with("client2_key");
    binding.setAdminsThatShouldDeclare(client2());
    return binding;
}

@Bean
@Primary
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    SimpleRoutingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new SimpleRoutingConnectionFactory();
    Map<Object, ConnectionFactory> targetConnectionFactories = new HashMap<>();
    targetConnectionFactories.put("client1", client1ConnectionFactory());
    targetConnectionFactories.put("client2", client2ConnectionFactory());
    connectionFactory.setTargetConnectionFactories(targetConnectionFactories);
    return connectionFactory;
}

@Bean
public ConnectionFactory client1ConnectionFactory() {
    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(connect.getRabbitMQHost());
    connectionFactory.setVirtualHost(connect.getRabbitMQClient1VHost());
    connectionFactory.setUsername(connect.getRabbitMQClient1User());
    connectionFactory.setPassword(connect.getRabbitMQClient1Pass());
    return connectionFactory;
}

@Bean
public ConnectionFactory client2ConnectionFactory() {
    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(connect.getRabbitMQHost());
    connectionFactory.setVirtualHost(connect.getRabbitMQClient2VHost());
    connectionFactory.setUsername(connect.getRabbitClient2User());
    connectionFactory.setPassword(connect.getRabbitClient2Pass());
    return connectionFactory;
}

// You can comment all methods below and remove interface's implementation to use the default serialization / deserialization
@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
    final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
    rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(producerJackson2MessageConverter());
    return rabbitTemplate;
}

@Bean
public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter producerJackson2MessageConverter() {
    return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
}

@Bean
public MappingJackson2MessageConverter consumerJackson2MessageConverter() {
    return new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
}

@Bean
public DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory messageHandlerMethodFactory() {
    DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory factory = new DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory();
    factory.setMessageConverter(consumerJackson2MessageConverter());
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public TaskExecutor rabbitListenerExecutor() {
    int threads = Integer.valueOf(connect.getMinConsumers()) * 2; // threads = min consumers* no of queues
    final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(threads);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(threads);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("RabbitThreadListener");
    executor.afterPropertiesSet();
    return executor;
}

@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory myRabbitListenerContainerFactory() {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    factory.setConcurrentConsumers(Integer.valueOf(connect.getMinConsumers()));
    factory.setPrefetchCount(Integer.valueOf(connect.getPrefetchCount()));
    factory.setTaskExecutor(rabbitListenerExecutor());
    factory.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL);
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public RabbitAdmin client1() {
    RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin = new RabbitAdmin(client1ConnectionFactory());
    rabbitAdmin.afterPropertiesSet();
    return rabbitAdmin;
}

@Bean
public RabbitAdmin client2() {
    RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin = new RabbitAdmin(client2ConnectionFactory());
    rabbitAdmin.afterPropertiesSet();
    return rabbitAdmin;
}
```

}

i'm getting this stacktrace

```
o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Consumer raised exception, 
processing can restart if the connection factory supports it
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot determine target ConnectionFactory for lookup key [null]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractRoutingConnectionFactory.determineTargetConnectionFactory(AbstractRoutingConnectionFactory.java:119)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractRoutingConnectionFactory.createConnection(AbstractRoutingConnectionFactory.java:97)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils$1.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:90)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:140)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.getTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:76)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:505)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1335)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `RoutingConnectionFactory` is generally used for publishing messages.

When using a routing factory in a listener container you must configure the lookup key to match the queue name(s) configured in the container.

From [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#routing-connection-factory):

> Also starting with version 1.4, you can configure a routing connection factory in a listener container. In that case, the list of queue names is used as the lookup key. For example, if you configure the container with `setQueueNames("foo", "bar")`, the lookup key will be `"[foo,bar]"` (no spaces).

So; if a `RabbitListener` listens to queue `foo` the routing lookup key must be `[foo]`. (You can add the same CF multiple times with different keys).

Or you can simply create multiple container factories, with each getting a concrete CF instead of the routing CF.

**EDIT**

Let's say you have

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "myQueue", connectionFactory = "myRabbitListenerContainerFactory")
public void listen(...) {
    ...
}
```

If `myQueue` is in `client1`'s vhost, then you need an entry in the router CF map thus...

```
targetConnectionFactories.put("[myQueue]", client1ConnectionFactory());
```

...because the listener container generated for the listener will use the queue name in its lookup key.

**Alternatively**, create 2 container factories; each wired directly with client1 and client2 CFs instead of the routing CF...

```
@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory client1ListenerContainerFactory() {

@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory client2ListenerContainerFactory() {
```

and

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "myQueue", connectionFactory = "client1ListenerContainerFactory")
public void listen(...) {
    ...
}
```

i.e. don't use the routing CF at all for listeners - containers only have one connection.

Comment: i'm quite new to rabbitmq forgive me if i dont get you properly. but you are saying the way i have implemented the routingConnectionFactory is wrong. essentially for it to work what would i have to change in the setup

Comment: No; you won't need them with option 2 since the listener containers will get the proper CF for their vhost directly from the container factory. The routing CF would only be used for publishing then. BTW, don't put code in comments; it's hard to read; it's best to edit the question and add a comment that you have done so.

Comment: aah now i get you. so if i have to go with option 2 will i still need to add all my queues here even if they are lets say 10.  

`targetConnectionFactories.put("[myQueue1]", client1ConnectionFactory());
targetConnectionFactories.put("[myQueue2]", client1ConnectionFactory());
targetConnectionFactories.put("[myQueue3]", client2ConnectionFactory());`

Comment: so how about the RabbitTemplate when sending. will I have to implement another rabbit template fro the second vhost?

Comment: See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#routing-connection-factory) about how to use a `RabbitTemplate` with a `RoutingConnectionFactory`. Or, indeed, you can use a different template for each. It really depends on how your application is structured as to which is best.